# Windows Phone 7 - Images & Themes in a databound listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a listbox that I'm doing some databinding.  As you can see I have some images associated with the data that I'm displaying...  Everything is working great, except that when I change themes I need to change my image to the black images.  I can't seem to figure out how to change the images when they are bound like this.

Any ideas?

```
            <ListBox x:Name="lbPharm" ItemsSource="{Binding col}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10">*</TextBlock>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding name}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemNumber" Text="{Binding number}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <Image Source="Images/phone.png" Margin="20,0" x:Name="phone" Visibility="Visible">
                                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                                    <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap_Phone"/>
                                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            </Image>


                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a binding for the image source instead of setting it explicitly in XAML.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbPharm" ItemsSource="{Binding col}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10">*</TextBlock>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding name}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ItemNumber" Text="{Binding number}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <!-- Image source is bound to a property -->
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Margin="20,0" x:Name="phone" Visibility="Visible">
                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap_Phone"/>
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                </Image>


            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now, just update the property in your view model as needed, as long as the class containing the property implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` the new image will show up in your `ListBox`.

The `ImageSource` property may have to be a `BitmapImage` instead of a string. XAML must use a converter to convert your path string when it is used as a literal but I think it doesn't do this if you use a binding. Or you could use your own converter. Either way, construct a `BitmapImage` as follows:

```
new BitmapImage( new Uri( "/path/to/image.png", UriKind.Relative ) )
```

**EDIT**

Adding an example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorItemTemplate">
  <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Orientation="Horizontal">

    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
      <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="OnTap" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

    <Image  Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
            MinHeight="32"
            MinWidth="32"
            MaxHeight="48"
            MaxWidth="48" />

    <StackPanel>

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                 Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                 Margin="12,10,12,0" />

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent}"
                 Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                 Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"
                 Margin="24,0,12,10" />

    </StackPanel>

  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Corresponding view model:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  #region Private Members
  private string _name = null; 
  private string _imageSource = null;
  private string _parent = null;
  #endregion

  public string Name
  {
    get
    {
      return _name;
    }
    set
    {
      if( value != _name ) {
        _name = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "Name" );
      }
    }
  }

  public string Parent
  {
    get
    {
      return _parent;
    }
    set
    {
      if( value != _parent ) {
        _parent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "Parent" );
      }
    }
  }

  public string ImageSource
  {
    get
    {
      return _imageSource;
    }
    set
    {
      if( value != _imageSource ) {
        _imageSource = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "ImageSource" );
      }
    }
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName )
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if( null != handler ) {
      handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
  }
  #endregion
}
```

This is code from a project I'm working on, it is similar to your case except I'm displaying the image with a `LongListSelector` instead of a `ListBox`. And it looks like I mislead you earlier about not being able to use a string directly for the image source, I'm doing exactly that and it works. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere that you know?  I'm having a difficult time getting my code to work...

Comment: @Jeff V: I added example code. I was wrong about the source needing to be a `BitmapImage`, my apologies.